# C programming: Finding the confusion matrix given the truth vector and prediction

Tags: c, matrix, confusion-matrix

Assume that we have given two vector of labels which one of them is the truth and the other one is the predicted ones. My question is how we can write a correct confusion matrix for it in C. This is a function which supposes to find the confusion matrix in a larger c code. I appreciate some help regarding this.

```
double ConfusionMatrix(int truth[], int prediction[]){  
/* The truth vector of labels, the predicted vector of labels, and the unique length of labels which should be given. */

    int i, j, c;
    int labels;  /* The length of unique labels */

    conf_mat = (float**)calloc(truth, sizeof(float*));  /* Allocating Memory to the Confusion Matrix. */

    for (i = 0; i < truth; i++)
        conf_mat[i] = (float*)calloc(truth, sizeof(float));

    for (i = 0; i < truth; i++)
        for (c = 0; c < truth; c++)
            conf_mat[c][i] = 0.0;
    for (j = 0; j < truth; j++){
        c = labels[j];
        for (i = 0; i < prediction; i++)
            conf_mat[c][i] += prediction[i][j];
    }


    /* As Confusion Matrix is sparse, then print only the entries above the threshold. */
    printf("Print the Confusion Matrix \n Print only the entries above 0.1\n");
    for (c = 0; c < truth; c++){
        printf("\n\nClass %d documents were classified in these classes\n", c);
        for (i = 0; i < truth; i++)
            if (conf_mat[c][i] >= 0.1)
                printf("class %d:%5.1f times  ", i, conf_mat[c][i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider that we have given these vectors:

Comment: Consider that we have given these vectors: truth[10] = {1, 2, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5}; prediction[10] = {1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5}.